# Why is LAST_VALUE() not working in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the data I have (note that this is for only one entity id / employee id, there will be multiple. One entity ID can have multiple employee IDs under it):

```
SELECT  EntityId,
        EmployeeId,
        PayPeriodStart,
        IsFullTime
FROM    dbo.Payroll
WHERE   EmployeeId = 316691
        AND PayPeriodStart <= '12/31/2014'
        AND PayPeriodEnd >= '1/1/2014';
```

[image]

I want to grab the LAST "IsFullTime" value FOR EACH EntityID & EmployeeID combo.

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT  EntityId,
        EmployeeId,
        LAST_VALUE(IsFullTime) OVER (PARTITION BY EntityId, EmployeeId ORDER BY EntityId, EmployeeId, PayPeriodStart) AS LastIsFullTimeValue
FROM    dbo.Payroll
WHERE   EmployeeId = 316691
        AND PayPeriodStart <= '12/31/2014'
        AND PayPeriodEnd >= '1/1/2014';
```

But I'm getting this:

[image]

The query should return only ONE row FOR EACH EntityID / EmployeeID.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server is this running against?? What is the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` ?? `LAST_VALUE` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** and not available in earlier versions

Comment: If you want "only ONE row FOR EACH EntityID / EmployeeID" you need to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
 Dec 28 2012 20:23:12 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: you need distinct or group by or row_number() in a sub-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking to use `ROW_NUMBER()` and the get the last value based on `payperiodstart` date:

```
SELECT t.EntityId
    ,t.EmployeeId
    ,t.LastIsFullTimeValue
FROM (
    SELECT EntityId
        ,EmployeeId
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY EntityId
            ,EmployeeId ORDER BY PayPeriodStart DESC
            ) AS rn
        ,LastIsFullTimeValue
    FROM dbo.Payroll
    WHERE EmployeeId = 316691   -- you could probably put this in your outer query instead
        AND PayPeriodStart <= '12/31/2014'
        AND PayPeriodEnd >= '1/1/2014'
    ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 26):

Try adding `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`

I believe the default window for analytic functions that includes an `ORDER BY` ends at the current row.

```
LAST_VALUE(IsFullTime) OVER (
    PARTITION BY EntityId, EmployeeId
    ORDER BY EntityId, EmployeeId, PayPeriodStart
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
) AS LastIsFullTimeValue
```

Comment: As I had put in my now-deleted answer, also use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get only one row for each `EntityId`/`EmployeeId` combination. Combined with your answer (and your answer contains the better information) that gives exactly the desired results. Otherwise, you need some sort of grouping or filtering like in FutbolFan's answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think that probably makes the most sense.

Comment: thanks for the help guys but FutbolFan's answer just ended up being easier to implement.

Comment: Any idea why `Lead` seems to work without specifying the frame?

Comment: @Joe I realized you were talking about a different function. The frame is basically defined by the second argument to the `lead()` function.

Comment: Upvoted for a) being right, b) noting the all important rule about default windows for analytic functions

Answer (score 18):

Here's the trick. I use `FIRST_VALUE` + `DESC` ordering (instead of `LAST_VALUE` + `ASC` ordering). Works. It is the shortest way and **it let you avoid dreaded** `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`.

```
FIRST_VALUE(IsFullTime) OVER (
    PARTITION BY EntityId, EmployeeId
    ORDER BY EntityId DESC, EmployeeId DESC, PayPeriodStart DESC
) AS LastIsFullTimeValue
```

Agreed, it is confusing why `LAST_VALUE` is not intuitive and requires so much attention compared to its twin sister `FIRST_VALUE`.

If you would like to care for performance, read this: https://sqlperformance.com/2019/08/sql-performance/t-sql-bugs-pitfalls-and-best-practices-window-functions

Comment: thanks, works for me perfectly! but I don't understand why last_value is not working

Comment: Why is it better to avoid the `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` ? Is it just the syntax or does it affect query performance?

Comment: I have been practicing FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE the past couple of days and got so confused by the latter.  As you indicated, FIRST_VALUE is pretty straightforward and intuitive, but LAST_VALUE is so un-intuitive, added to the conundrum is the alien language of unbounded preceding and unbounded following. Now I think I understand how LAST_VALUE works. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

To see what is happening, you must understand the concept of framing. The frame allows you to specify a set of rows for the window that is even smaller than the partition. The default frame contains the rows starting with the first row and up to the current row. For row 1, the window is just row 1. For row 3, the window contains rows 1 to 3. When using FIRST_VALUE, the first row is included by default, so you don’t have to worry about it to get the expected results.

When using LAST_VALUE with the default frame, the window only goes up to the current row. The current row is the last row of the window. To get around this problem, you must specify the frame, in this case ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING. This means that the window starts with the current row and ends at the last row of the partition. Run the next example to see how to use LAST_VALUE correctly.

view http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/124112/

Comment: Thank you for making clear the bewildering behavior of LAST_VALUE as I have been struggling with it for days.