# SQL Server LAST_VALUE and LEAD

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

As demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884513/why-is-last-value-not-working-in-sql-server), the `LAST_VALUE` function in SQL Server need to have a frame specified (eg.  `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`) or the default will be the first row through the current row. This does not seem to be the case for `LEAD`.  Both functions are "forward looking" so is there any documented reason for what appears to be an inconsistency?

Everything is working as expected, I am just trying to gain a more solid understanding of functionality that I have been using for years.

Comment: Are you sure that's the case? LAST_VALUE and LAG/LEAD both use OVER() in the same way. They don't need a PARTITION BY frame necessarily.

Comment: The default scope for `LAST_VALUE` is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, as a result if you want all the rows after included, you need to use a specified range. `LEAD`, on the other hand, doesn't use `ROWS_BETWEEN` or `RANGE`, so has access to the entire scope of the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default window frame for `LAST_VALUE` is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, as a result if you want all the rows after included, you need to use a specified window fra,e. This is documented in [LAST_VALUE (Transact-SQL) - Using FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE in a computed expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#feedback):

> The clause "RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING" is required in this example for the non-zero values to be returned in the DifferenceFromLastQuarter column, as shown below. The default range is "RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW".

As a result, without `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` then you would get the current row with `LAST_VALUE` as that is the last row in the default window frame.

`LEAD`, on the other hand, doesn't use `ROWS` or `RANGE BETWEEN`, so has access to the entire scope of the dataset. Trying to use `ROWS BETWEEN` will generate an error:

```
SELECT V.I,
       LEAD(V.I) OVER (ORDER BY V.I ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS L
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3))V(I);
```

> The function 'LEAD' may not have a window frame.